# Show tax from shipping?

Tags: commerce

I'm building on [Commerce Kickstart 2](https://drupalcommerce.org/commerce-kickstart-2). The problem is that for shipping it displays only flat price, there is no tax amount calculated seperately.

Is it possible to shipping like:

Express shipping subtotal 10€
Shipping tax 23% 1,23€
Total: 11,23€

Or show shipping as line item so that shipping tax is calculated to product taxes amount?

Comment: Yes Commerce does that by default, make sure you configure it correctly
check here for a great [Tutorial](http://www.drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/tax-configuration)

Comment: Just a quick comment which you say not to do. But the videos do not cover tax on shipping.

Comment: Did you check the link in my answer?

Comment: saadlulu, the video doesn't show how to calculate tax on the shipping line item, which is treated separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using Tax option under store-> configuration.

Just go and add a tax rate.

Now you can apply tax rate using rules easily on event something like "after saving new commerce order.

And then add action you want to perform.

Answer (score 0):

The way to approach this is to add your tax rate at a calculation in shipping. Set your conditional tax first and then add an additional calculation rule to your shipping. This calculates correctly, but appears as though there's a higher tax on the products.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty absurd this isn't the default methodology but the commerce price components module solves this glaring problem. https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_price_components

If you install it with Drush it'll install faster and then you can clear your cache right after which you will need to do to use this module.
`drush en -y commerce_price_components;drush cc all;`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try configuring a Shipping tax type plugin? (Under admin/commerce/config/tax-types). Make sure to select "Shipping" as the tax type plugin.