# Tax calculation Drupal Commerce

Tags: commerce

I've set-up a Drupal Commerce website. Clients add products in the backend and give each product a price INCLUDING taxes (in this case €160,00). The product fiches on the product page should show the products with taxes. In the shopping-cart block (in the sidebar) as well.

However, on the check-out pages, the line items should be shown WITHOUT taxes (€126,40 in this case). The taxes should only be added in the block on the bottom...

I hope I make myself clear with this picture:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea on how to do this? Because I don't :)

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/45630/4471

Answer (score 1):

The [Commerce Price Components](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_price_components) module allows you to change what elements of a price are included when displaying it, including whether tax is included in the amount.  With that module, you can get the result you are looking for by editing the view behind your Checkout screen (from your screenshot).

1. Go to the Checkout screen so it looks like your screenshot.  In other words, be sure you have a VAT tax set up, and a product in your shopping cart, and go to Checkout.  The screen will look as you show above, ie the line item price will INCLUDE VAT.
2. There is a gear icon in the upper right of the screen (above the word TOTAL).  Hover over this and click EDIT VIEW.
3. You will be in the Commerce Cart Summary View.  In the FIELDS list, click on the Commerce Line Item Unit Price.
4. Change the Formatter to Price By Components, and be sure only Base Price is ticked.
5. Click APPLY
6. Do the same for the Commerce Line Item Total.
7. Click SAVE to save the View

Answer (score 0):

Check this module: http://drupal.org/project/commerce_extra_price_formatters
After that change the view that displays the products and simply change the format of that price, you have multiple options with that module including the one to show it without taxes.

Hope it helps.